# Xcode XCTestCase not run at all

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest

I have some strange problem in xcode.

I haved project and I decided to add some Unit tests.

I create new Test bundle and add my app as test target. 
Only think that I change to auto generated code is :

```
Build Settings / Arhitectures / Build Active Arhitecture Only  : NO
```

and I add new test :

```
- (void)testExample {
    XCTAssertTrue(YES, @"OK");
}
```

When I run tests it builds ok and it says that running test, but test failed 
[image]

But as you can see no test is actually running.

Do any one have any idea why?

EDIT :

I have add test bundle into schema.

[image]

Marko

Answer (score 1):

A couple of observations:

- The test that is failing is inside the "BIView Mobile New VersionTests", not the test inside the "ModelUnitTest".
- In terms of whether the "ModelUnitTest" is included in the test, you have to edit the scheme and review the "Test" settings:

  [image: tests settings in scheme]

  Make sure your "ModelUnitTest" target is included in that list.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply. I already have this set (see my edit), but how do you see that BIView Mobile New VersionTests is failing?

Comment: @MarkoZadravec - See the left panel of your first image. "BIView Mobile New VersionTests" is collapsed and in light gray, but it's reporting that there is one failed test there.

Comment: But "BIView Mobile New VersionTests" is collapsed and light gray even before I start tests.

Comment: @MarkoZadravec - It doesn't matter that it's collapsed or not. It's clearly indicating that it ran a test there and it failed. So I'd expand it and navigate to the test that it reports failed. Why it's in gray escapes me. Personally, this all seems very weird so I'd suggest navigating to the `DerivedData` folder (found in Xcode "Preferences" - "Locations"), quitting Xcode, delete everything in that folder, and then restart Xcode. If the problem persists, zip it up for us and upload it somewhere where we can take a look at it. This is hard to diagnose via chat...

Comment: Hi, I try what you suggested and delete Derived data and delete  BIView Mobile New VersionTests bundle, but it didn't change anything. I can't zip code because I am paid developer in company :D I know it is very hard do this via chat, but is there anything that I can try...

Comment: We need [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem. So either create sample project free of any confidential information that exhibits the problem, or outline the precise steps that we need to do in order to reproduce the problem you describe. (As an aside, often in the process of trying to reproduce the problem in a new project, you'll identify the source of the problem in your existing project.)